# Deleting fixed number of characters when specific word is encountered R

Tags: r

I have a data set thats of the format

```
ID     Content
1      2020-01-01 Car1 Technician1  Inspected parts
2      2020-01-01 Car2 Technician1   Inspected wipers
3      2020-05-01 Car5 Technician2   Fixed wipers
```

I want to clean this up such that each time I encounter `Technician` I am removing the preceding `15` characters.
So my result would look like

```
ID     Content
1      1 Inspected parts
2      1 Inspected wipers
3      2 Fixed wipers
```

I am trying some `wild card` matching but have not been successful yet.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Why did you remove `Technician2`?

Comment: Why is it exactly 15 characters? With this content, it seems that you need to either remove (a) everything before, or (b) between the year and the technician.

Comment: And technically, since you want to remove 15 characters and the `T` is at character 17, you should be retaining something of the beginning of the strings.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the query above. Its exactly 15 characters, as they are some sort of auto added entry, which span 15 chars.

Comment: Your output is not consistent. If you remove precisely 15 characters from the first one, you get `"21  Inspected parts"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your output is inconsistent, but the premise of removing preceding characters can be done with the `{m,n}` ["limiting repetition"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) clause of regular expressions.

```r
gsub(".{15}Technician", "", dat$Content)
# [1] "21  Inspected parts"   "21   Inspected wipers" "22   Fixed wipers "
```

Note that `{15}` will work as long as there are 15 *or more* characters to remove. For example, nothing is done here.

```r
gsub(".{17}Technician", "", dat$Content)
# [1] "2020-01-01 Car1 Technician1  Inspected parts"   "2020-01-01 Car2 Technician1   Inspected wipers"
# [3] "2020-05-01 Car5 Technician2   Fixed wipers "
```

If you need "up to", then specify both numbers (or both positions) in the range, where an empty slot implies min or max:

```r
gsub(".{0,15}Technician", "", dat$Content)
gsub(".{,15}Technician", "", dat$Content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can be useful:

```
#Code
df$Content2 <- gsub(".*Technician", "", df$Content)
```

Output:

```
df
  ID                                        Content             Content2
1  1   2020-01-01 Car1 Technician1  Inspected parts   1  Inspected parts
2  2 2020-01-01 Car2 Technician1   Inspected wipers 1   Inspected wipers
3  3     2020-05-01 Car5 Technician2   Fixed wipers     2   Fixed wipers
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple application of regular expression matching and replacement. A functional solution is provided.

As noted in the comments above, hardcoding 15 characters is not recommended.

```
custom_regexreplace <- function(x, keyword= 'Technician') {
  len_key = nchar(keyword)
  loc <- regexpr(keyword, x)
  return(unlist(
    mapply(function(input, N) {substr(input, start= ifelse(N < 1, 1, N + len_key), stop= nchar(input))}
           , input= x, N= loc, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  ))
}

test <- c('2020-01-01 Car1 Technician1  Inspected parts', '2020-01-01 Car2 Technician1   Inspected wipers', '2020-05-01 Car5 Technician2   Fixed wipers ')
custom_regexreplace(test, keyword= 'Technician')
# output: 
# "1  Inspected parts"
# "1   Inspected wipers"
# "2   Fixed wipers "
```